# Disciplinary action for nasty behaviour

Tags: discussion, flagging, suggested-edits, moderation

A couple of hours ago I reviewed  a proposal to edit a post. The suggested edit was nasty, irrelevant and of pornographic nature. I rejected the edit choosing the reason for rejection as "harmful". I added a comment saying I recommend the user who suggested the edit be expelled.  Will this get escalated and such an action be taken on that user?

Comment: The edit in question was proposed anonymously (you can propose edits without being logged in), so I'm not sure much can be done in this case...

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen xD

Comment: Seriously though, if the perpetrator is a repeat offender, the moderators or the staff themselves can take action against the perpetrator's network (by banning them or something similar).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As it stands, having merely rejected the edit and given a custom reason won't draw the moderator's attention. For that, the appropriate course of action would be to flag the post to which the edit was suggested for moderator attention, and explain the problem and ideally provide a link to the suggested edit (which you can find under the "activity" tab of your profile under "all actions" under "reviews").

Comment: Thanks for the info about "Activity" tab. I took a screenshot. As Eric has commented it would be futile as the mischief was  done anonymously.

Comment: I think it is highly desirable to flag the post in question (and not something else), as then the flag takes the mod to the right place. (For example the post history will contain [a link to] the suggested edit, and there might be more than one etc.)

Comment: @quid Do mods see rejected suggestions in post history? In any case, you're right that the post itself is the most relevant thing to flag and would be of use to the moderators in locating the edit, so I edited my answer here.

Comment: Yes, moderators have such information at hand on the post. (But my choice of word "post history" was poor, as it suggests it is under /revisions, like the approved one for everybody, which is not the case.)